# Android listview shows on top of itself when scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll

By this I mean that when I scroll the listview, what originally showed on the screen appears to now show as a background with the listview scrolling above it.  All the items functionally are fine, but this causes the list view to look like crap cause you can see items under it.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: May you please post your .xml file here?

Comment: And/or probably a screenshot because it's not really clear what happens here